# Disallow 512mb tablets from downloading app on ios?

Tags: ios, ipad

The [UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1397/_index.html) key is the 'usual' way to disallow certain incompatible devices from downloading your app on the App Store. I have a tablet-only app that requires a large amount of memory. So much memory that it cannot work on 512MB devices (and it is unrealistic for it to work on such devices). [The table at this link here](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix) provides the compatibility for devices, but no such value exists. Essentially there are two devices: the iPad 2 and the iPad mini that we cannot support.

Has anyone been able to submit to the app store and not support <1GB devices? How would I go about doing that?

Since people may be inclined to think that I should 'just reduce the amount of memory used', this is irrelevant to the question at hand. I am familiar with memory management, texture compression, etc, and not looking for optimization advice.

Comment: I'm interested to know (and I guess others will too) on what the app is doing that requires so much memory?

Comment: I understand your interest. It is mostly texture memory.

Comment: I'm not aware of any explicit way to stop these devices downloading the app. Excuse me for the flippant comment, but surely the question should be how to reduce how much memory you're using for textures and not how to stop certain devices for installing your app? For reference the Sony PS3 only has 256MB CPU and 256MB GPU memory!

Comment: Nope, that is not the question I'm asking, nor do I want to tangent to optimization strategies.

Comment: Then you're out of luck I'm afraid. I can't see any combination of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities that would stop iPad mini and the iPad 2. Worst case scenario you could detect those devices on app launch and show the user an alert stating that the app doesn't work on their devices. I'm interested in why you don't want to discuss optimisation, sometimes asking the right question is half of the battle.